# Joomla Gantry 4.1.31 menu header produces 404

Tags: joomla, menu, http-status-code-404

I have 5 Joomla sites running the Gantry Framework. I had never noticed this until a user pointed it out, if you click on ANY pulldown menu header you get a 404 page not found error when you really shouldn't get anything!

[You can see this here!](http://www.themanpuzzle.com/)

The top level pulldown is defined as a system->menu header - no other settings so have I done something wrong all this time?

(Please don't suggest that I upgrade to Gantry5. Tried it and it's worse than bad buttermilk!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Gantry specific issue but rather a Joomla configuration issue.

For non active menus, use the "Text Separator" menu option rather than "Menu Heading":

[image]